# unable to send R code from a knitr document to SublimeREPL

Tags: r, sublimetext, sublimetext3, knitr, sublimerepl

I'm using Sublime 3, and I have a very simple question. SublimeREPL is working perfectly with R files, and Sublime compiles perfectly the knitr files (using LaTeXing)

But if I want to send R code from a knitr file (.Rnw) I get the following error:

Cannot find REPL for 'tex.latex.knitr.ing'

(I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 by the way)

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess SublimeREPL uses the file type to decide which REPL to use. It doesn't treat as R code. Would you please provide more details, so we can see if there is a workaround?

Comment: I'll be glad to give more details, but what exactly? And shortly after making this post, I found [this in SublimeREPL's github] (https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/165#issuecomment-56186887). So since R code in knitr is supposed to be a feature of SublimeREPL, I wonder if someone at all managed to make it work.

Comment: OK, I googled what knitr and had a try with Sublime Text 2. It worked well: the selected code could be sent to R REPL.

Comment: and what about Sublime Text 3? Did you have the same problem as I had?

Comment: I don't have Sublime Text 3. So I am sorry I don't know.

Comment: I installed a Sublime Text 3 on Windows. It worked. So I might be a platform related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so someone solved it here: https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/165#issuecomment-57658359

Just in case someone has the same problem:
this file has to be edited:

~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/R/Main.sublime-menu

and the aditional scope has to be modified in this way::
 "additional_scopes": ["tex.latex.knitr.ing"]