# How to send code to SublimeREPL in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl, rnw

I am using LaTeXing, SublimeREPL, and R-Box to work with .Rnw files so I can have LaTeX with R code chunks. However, when I try to go to "Tools->SublimeREPL->Eval in REPL->Line" I get the following error.

Cannot find REPL for 'tex.latex.knitr.ing'

I've tried Googling for an answer but couldn't find a relevant solution that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your question is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935129/unable-to-send-r-code-from-a-knitr-document-to-sublimerepl) and [here](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/165#issuecomment-57658359).

Quoted from the first link:

> > > Just in case someone has the same problem: this file has to be edited:
> > >
> > > ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/R/Main.sublime-menu
> > >
> > > and the aditional scope has to be modified in this way:: "additional_scopes": ["tex.latex.knitr.ing"]