# How to run R Code in R Markdown file in SublimeREPL?

Tags: r, sublimetext, r-markdown, sublimerepl

I would like to test code parts in my R Markdown code without leaving Sublime Text.

For instance:

````
Multiplying the grades with two solves the unreliability problem:
```{r}
 chisq.test(2*grades)
```
````

In the above example, I would like to select the line that has the code "chisq.test(2*grades)", press my key combination, and have it ran in SublimeREPL as R code.

However, when I try this, I get the following error from SublimeREPL:

> Cannot find REPL for 'HTML.markdown.rmarkdown'

When I change the syntax through view menu to "R" (rather than R Markdown), the code runs fine. This is a workaround though, and it is undesirable because it costs me R Markdown syntax highlighting.

I suspect the solution is simply copy-pasting a few lines of SublimeREPL package code and repurposing them for R Markdown, but I was unable to achieve any results yet. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25935129/unable-to-send-r-code-from-a-knitr-document-to-sublimerepl) :

1. Open the file `SublimeREPL/config/R/Main.sublime-menu`. Its default position depends on your system

   - Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
   - Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` (untested)
   - Windows: `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text 3/Packages` (untested)
2. Add your scode to the option "additional_scopes":

   ```
   "additional_scopes": ["HTML.markdown.rmarkdown","tex.latex.knitr"],
   ```
3. Save the file, close the REPL tab, restart sublime, and open a new REPL instance.

Comment: Thanks scoa! This solution works perfectly.

A note: It was not clear to me that the SublimeREPL tab in Sublime Text had to be closed and reopened for the solution to start working. After a few failed tries, I saw that this is what you meant when you said "restart REPL" (I previously thought restarting Sublime Text would restart it as well).

Comment: Don't know why but it seems like the name of the scope changed: I got the same error with "html.markdown.knitr" instead of "HTML.markdown.rmarkdown". Adding "html.markdown.knitr" in "additional_scopes" solved it.

Comment: Can I just clarify. Does this file and set of folders need to be created? They don't exist for me... I'm using OS X

Comment: It depends on the OS. I updated the answer (but this is untested as I don't use OS X)